# Unwanted Extra Spaces in \newcommand and \detokenize for Verbatim Text

Tags: spacing, verbatim, detokenize

I'm trying to make a `newcommand` to print verbatim text using the `\detokenize` as follows:

```
\newcommand{\texcmd}[1]{%
    {\color{red!70}{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}}
}
```

When I use it to typeset a long command like `\texcmd{\newcommand{\cmd}{def}}`, it produces extra spaces as shown

---

### [image]

---

How can I get rid of those unwanted spaces?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks a lot.